# mailgun Error":"exposed account credentials

Tags: runtime-error, mailgun

I am attempting to validate an email but when I follow the mailgun docs and have code such as follows

https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#email-validation

```
EMAILPUBLICVALIDATIONKEY = 'my sexy key'

def validateemail(emailaddress):
    return requests.get(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/validate",
        auth=("api", EMAILPUBLICVALIDATIONKEY ),
        params={'address': emailaddress}
    )
```

I get the response

```
["{"Error":"exposed account credentials"}"]0: "{"Error":"exposed account credentials"}"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: That error looks like you accidentally leaked your API keys or something and they got deactivated. But I've never had that error before so I really can't be certain.

Comment: damn. Ok it was in my last github push I bet. Thanks man make it an answer so I can give you those sexy points

Comment: GitHub recently announced a feature where they will notify companies when API keys get exposed. I'm still trying to find a link and will update my answer if I ever find it. I don't THINK Mailgun was on that list. But they could have been added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't actually gotten this error in MailGun before. But I'm assuming `exposed account credentials` means that your API key got exposed and they deactivated it in order to try to protect you.

Kinda unrelated, but GitHub recently released a feature where they will scan commits for API keys and tokens and notify the company that it was exposed. Doesn't look like as of posting this MailGun is on that list, but there is also a slim chance since it's in beta that list hasn't been updated. https://help.github.com/articles/about-token-scanning/

Comment: I can confirm that Mailgun do get notified - I have a student who uploaded his code containing the Mailgun API key, and his Mailgun account was suspended... he did this repeatedly (with a new Mailgun account each time!) until we informed him otherwise :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely due to exposing a Mailgun API key on Github. I had the API key in a file and commented it out but still got flagged. If you file a ticket on Mailgun, a reply will be sent with these instructions:

```
    Due to the compromise, you will need to take a few steps to secure your Mailgun account:

    - Remove the repository from Github or making the repository private. A new commit will not overwrite the previous commit history which contains the password.
    - Please log in to the Mailgun Control Panel and reset your Mailgun account password. Click your email address in the top right, "Edit Account Info" -> "Password Change" section.
    - Enable 2 Factor Authentication. Click your email address in the top right > Security > Two-Factor Authentication section.
    - Reset your Mailgun API key. Under "Account Settings" -> "Security" click the refresh symbol to generate a new API key.
    - Reset your SMTP credentials. Go to the "Domains" tab and repeat the following process for each domain listed in this view.
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't THINK Mailgun was on that list. But they could have been added.

It is official now (May 23rd, 2019): "[Token scanning](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-23-token-scanning/)"

> Token scanning is now generally available in all public repositories.
>
> Additionally, token scanning now supports detection of new token types from Alibaba Cloud, **Mailgun**, and Twilio.

The full list is on "[**About token scanning**](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-token-scanning)".
See more at "[**Token scanning**](https://developer.github.com/partnerships/token-scanning/)".

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your Mailgun account, a banner will say that your account has been suspended, then you have to contact support to unlock it